# Copy entire filesystem in a folder where a raid-1 array is mounted

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, raid, rsync, cp

I am trying to **migrate** from a single disk drive system to a double disk drive software raid-1 system that **already has a running system** on it. Meaning that formatting and having a new installation of ubuntu using raid-1 is NOT an option.

In this process I have to **copy the contents** from main disk (/dev/sda1) to mounted raid array (/dev/md0).

First Attempt to Copy:

```
sudo cp -dpRx / /mnt/md1
```

Second Attempt to Copy:

```
sudo rsync -avxHAXS --delete --progress / /mnt/md1
```

Both of them end with warnings. Not sure if they end successfully.

**Which command** should I use (from the two above or something else like `dd`) and with **which parameters** in order to have the md1 raid-array prepared for next reboot?

**EDIT**:
This is the warning message I got from "cp" command on my first attempt:

```
cp: cannot stat `/home/george/.gvfs': Permission denied
```

This is the error message I got from "rsync" command on my second attempt:

```
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Comment: You need to specify what warnings.

Comment: Ok I ll do that right away

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the warning, this is a longstanding bug.  The .gvfs directory is a virtual filesystem used to map things like network connections you make with nautilus.  It can not be accessed by root, even enough to see that it is a virtual filesystem and thus, should be skipped.